# React-Native Listview, press row and change that row style

Tags: list, react-native

I had horizontal listview, and I want to press row and change row style. ( selected row : change style row  ,unselected row : change to default style). I use touchable highlight on row of it. any suggestion for it ?. I try to search about 3 days already. but I still cannot catch it. thank advance.

```
class MatchSchedule extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._getWeekList()),
        selectedID: 'Week 3',
    };
     render() {
       return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.weekContain}>
                <ListView
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    horizontal={true}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                >
                </ListView>
            </View>
        </View>
      );}
    _renderRow(rowData, rowID) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
            this._selectedWeek(rowData, rowID)
        }
        }
        >
            <View style={this.state.selectedID == rowData ? styles.weekRowSelected : styles.weekRow}>
                <Text style={this.state.selectedID == rowData ? styles.weekTextSelected : styles.weekText}> {rowData} </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );
}
 _selectedWeek(rowData, rowID) {
    this.setState({
        selectedID: rowData,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newDs)
    });
}   
}
```

I am try to re-render listview also, but still cannot. I am new react-native.

Comment: Set an array of the 'pressed' row IDs in state, and add to this on press. Then re-render your list view with the changed style based on row index existing in said array. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow you can get the row ID from the `renderRow` method.

Comment: the re-render is the best solution. may u bring me the re-render simple? sorry I am new react-native @Godsquad

Comment: @RishabhBhatia posted pretty much the code for what I described below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Leang refer to this thread [React native: change style of ListView item on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118467/react-native-change-style-of-listview-item-on-touch) Use below code to get started

```
class ListExample extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 === r2
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._getWeekList()),
      selectedID: 'tues'
    }
  }

  _getWeekList = () => {
    return ["monday", "tues", "wed", "thurs"]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.weekContain}>
          <ListView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal={true} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}></ListView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
  _renderRow(rowData, rowID) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
        this._selectedWeek(rowData, rowID)
      }}>
        <View style={this.state.selectedID == rowData
          ? styles.weekRowSelected
          : styles.weekRow}>
          <Text style={this.state.selectedID == rowData
            ? styles.weekTextSelected
            : styles.weekText}>
            {rowData} {this.state.selectedID}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
  _selectedWeek(rowData, rowID) {
    console.log('Selected week '+rowData);
    this.setState({selectedID: rowData, dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this._getWeekList())});
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  weekRowSelected : {
  },
  weekRow: {
  },
  weekTextSelected: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'yellow',
  },
  weekText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: 'blue',
  }
})
```

Leang looking at the code you added

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    });
```

in here you have told react to re-render the list only when data changes, whereas it isn't changing. To make it work you have to either modify your ds and then pass it or simply change the above condition to

```
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 === r2,
    });
```

I tried this code myself and it works. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Hi Leang, this is for listview. Keep your render() function and use above code. Let me add a render function to help you understand above code.

Comment: I did that, but when this.selectItem(item) method process, it's not re-render the listview.

Comment: This is propably the correct answer,  you 're just forgetting to apply the viewStyle  to the view :)

Comment: Ok Leang, thanks for adding code. Let me test your code and get back.

Comment: @Rishabh. yes i got something that i want. i will tick u.  thank u