# React Native: In an array of Text Inputs which are looped then displayed, how to get nth element and modify those elements separately?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, twitter

In this module I am trying to create a survey module similar to the one in twitter.

at first, color of text input borders are grey and when I focus (click) the text input, only one of them (clicked one) must be blue. Same idea when I type a text, they all shouldn't get the same value. I should be able to get each text input value that I created by clicking plus icon, as a String

Should I use a flatlist or a listview rather than a for loop ? 
[React-Native Listview, press row and change that row style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934061/react-native-listview-press-row-and-change-that-row-style?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I also tried to solve it according to this example.
I change this example a little bit, I was able to change border color of clicked one. but still, I couldn't get the values...

Any solution suggestion ? Thank you.

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuupI.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0cym.png)

This is my code;

```
changeInputBorderColor = () => {
    const newinputBorderColor = cloneDeep(this.state.inputBorderColor);
    newinputBorderColor.bar = '#04A5F5';
    this.setState({inputBorderColor: {bar: newinputBorderColor.bar}});
};
changeInputBorderColor2 = () => {
    this.setState({
        inputBorderColor: {
            bar: 'grey'
        }
    })
};
incrementInputCount = () => {
    if (this.state.inputCounter < 5) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {inputCounter: prevState.inputCounter + 1}
        });
        console.log(this.state.inputCounter);
    }
    else {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {inputCounter: prevState.inputCounter}
        });
        alert("Maximum soru sayısına ulaştınız");
    }
};

render() {
    let surveyOptions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.inputCounter; i++) {
        console.log(this.state.inputCounter);
        surveyOptions.push(
            <View key={i}>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        style={[styles._surveyTextInput, {borderColor: this.state.inputBorderColor.bar}]}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onFocus={this.changeInputBorderColor}
                        onBlur={this.changeInputBorderColor2}
                        placeholder={"Secenek " + (i + 1)}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles._surveyMainContainer}>
            <View style={{flex: 0.8}}>
                {surveyOptions}
                <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute', right: 5, top: 5}}>
                    <Ionicons name={"ios-close-circle"}
                              size={30}
                              color={'black'}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute', right: 5, top: 45}}
                                  onPress={this.incrementInputCount}>
                    <Ionicons name={"ios-add-circle"}
                              size={30}
                              color={'blue'}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 0.2}}>
                <View
                    style={styles.renderSeparator}
                />
                <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', margin: 5}}>Anket süresi</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: You should copy and paste your code into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `.map` however you have to set it up correctly so that each `TextInput` has its own value in state. Currently what you are doing is setting the same value in state for each `TextInput` this results in every `TextInput` having the same value. Clearly not what you want.

1. Create an initial array in state (`textArray`) that has all values as empty strings, this will be used to store the values from each `TextInput`.
2. Set the `focusedIndex` to be null in state
3. Create a function that uses the previous state value to update the current state.
4. Create a function to handle the changing of the box color, it will just compare the `TextInput` index with the current `focusedIndex`
5. Iterate over the `textArray` and create the `TextInput` components. Make sure each `TextInput` has its own value in state.
6. Make sure we set the value of the focusedIndex in the `onFocus` and `onBlur` in the `TextInput`. When it blurs we should set the value to null so that it removes the border color when the keyboard is dismissed.

So we could do something like the following

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // construct an array with the number of textInputs we require, 
    // each value an empty string
    // set this array in state
    // set the focusedIndex to null
    let textArray = Array(6).fill('');
    this.state = {
      textArray: textArray,
      focusedIndex: null
    }
  }

  // this function will handle setting of the state when each TextInput changes
  onChangeText = (text, index) => {
    // as there are going to be a lot of setState calls
    // we need access the prevState before we set the next state.
    this.setState(prevState => {
      prevState.textArray[index] = text
      return {
        textArray: prevState.textArray
      }
    }, () => console.log(this.state.textArray))
  }

  // handle the border color
  handleBorderColor = (index) => {
    return index === this.state.focusedIndex ? 'red' : 'grey'
  }

  render() {
    // here we map the items in the `this.state.textArray` 
    // notice that each TextInput is give a specific value in state
    // that will stop the overlap
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.textArray.map((text, index) => {
          return <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, marginVertical: 10, borderColor: this.handleBorderColor(index), borderWidth: 1}}
            onChangeText={text => this.onChangeText(text, index)} 
            value={this.state.textArray[index]}
            placeholder={`placeholder for ${index}`}
            onFocus={() => this.setState({focusedIndex: index})}
            onBlur={() => this.setState({focusedIndex: null})}
          />
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If you then want to access a specific value for a `TextInput` you can do so like this

```
let value = this.state.textArray[index]; // where the index is the value you want
```

Here is an example snack showing the code working 
https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/map-multiple-textinputs

It is definitely worthwhile looking at the following articles about state, as I have used these properties in this example.

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296
https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6